# Linking text nodes in a page

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, node-connections

I'd like to know what package can link nodes in different parts of a page.
To simplify my question I uploaded an example extracted of tkz-linknodes manual (AlterMundus). Please note that the page shows exactly what I need, but the manual doesn't explain how can I do that (actually, the tkz-linknodes package is applied to equation environments).

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Where is the example you say you've uploaded?

Comment: N. N. When I wrote the question I hadn't yet realized that I can't upload images if I am a newcomer. So, excuse me. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `tkz-linknodes`'s features not only for math expressions:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-linknodes}

\begin{document}

\begin{NodesList}[margin=7cm]
Lorem ipsum\AddNode dolor sit amet, consectetuer
  adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
  adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu
  libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer\AddNode[2] id, vulputate a, magna. Donec
  vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
  senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut
  leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna
  fringilla ultrices.  Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida
  placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis\AddNode in, pretium quis, viverra ac,
  nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus.
  Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla.
  Curabitur auctor semper nulla\AddNode[2]. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis
  nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis
  eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.
  \tikzset{ArrowStyle/.style={->,cyan}}
  \LinkNodes{}
  \LinkNodes[margin=8cm]{}
\end{NodesList}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As Altermundus mentions, you can look at the sources of the `tkz-linknodes` documentation: [TKZdoc-linknodes-us.tex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-linknodes/doc/latex/TKZdoc-linknodes-us.tex). In that file you can find the code for all the examples.

Comment: @Eloy Mello: You're welcome! Since my response seems to answer your question, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below its vote count.