# Nodes linked by a horizontal arrow in enumerate environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, enumerate, node-connections

Alright, here's what I need. I need links between nodes *a la* [`tkz-linknodes`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20620/linking-text-nodes-in-a-page), but, unlike that package, I need linking arrows that appear **beneath** the sentence as opposed to linking arrows that appear in the right margin.

And here's another constraint. I would like this to work in an `enumerate` environment. So, for example, I would like to be able have something like this

```
    \begin{quote}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item[(1)] \node{A man} walked in. \node{He} sat down. 
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{quote}
```

where there is an arrow that starts with the pronoun *he* and which then points back to the noun phrase *a man*. And like the arrows in `tkz-linknodes`, I want this to be a non-curved arrow with right angles.

Maybe this can be done easily in TiKz, but I'm having trouble doing this in a way that plays nice with the `enumerate` environment and I can't seem to get `tkz-linknodes` to do this either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Something like [Can TikZ emulate PSTricks' inline \Rnodes, scattered along a complex equation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133273) or [How to highlight a pair of terms with compact, rectangular, semi-transparent, colored regions?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134762/16595)

Comment: Yes!

I used [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133298/37583) technique in the first link you gave, and it works great in an `enumerate` environment. The code is a little ugly, but it does the trick.