# How to draw markup language structure?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to highlight the structure of a formatting language that uses tags somewhat related to HTML, but with different capabilities regarding the closing tags. I'm thinking of something like this:

[image: mockup]

What options do I have to draw the brackets that explain the structure without the help of additional graphics software?

(I'm using pdflatex...)

Comment: Related: [How to highlight a pair of terms with compact, rectangular, semi-transparent, colored regions?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134697), [Can TikZ emulate PSTricks' inline \Rnodes, scattered along a complex equation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133273) and [Nodes linked by a horizontal arrow in enumerate environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136009); coming from [Is there a TikZ equivalent to the PSTricks \ncbar command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55068)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated**

A TikZ solution.

The implementation relies on a pair of commands `\open` and `\close` for the HTML syntax (and `\openvar`, `\closevar` for the other syntax). The commands are defined as follows:

```
\newcommand\open[1]{
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(open#1.base)]{\node(open#1){<#1>};}
}

\newcommand\close[3][red]{
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(close#2.base)]{
        \node(close#2){</#2>};
        \draw[#1,overlay](open#2)to[ncbar=#3](close#2);
    }
}
```

The `-var` version of the commands for the second syntax are similarly defined.

The `\open` command takes one argument, i.e. the name of the open tag. The `\close` command takes 3 arguments:

1. the first optional argument sets the color of the "bracket" connected the open and close tags (with default set to `red`);
2. the second argument is the name of the close tag;
3. the third argument determines the height of the "bracket". Note that the bracket is implemented by the `ncbar` style, provided by [Jake's answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55069/18228).

**Full code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% ncbar style - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55069/18228
\tikzset{
    ncbar angle/.initial=90,
    ncbar/.style={
        to path=(\tikztostart)
        -- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)
        -- ($(\tikztotarget)!($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztostart)$)
        -- (\tikztotarget)
    },
    ncbar/.default=0.5cm,
}

\tikzset{every node/.style={inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}} % remove unnecessary space

% HTML syntax
\newcommand\open[1]{
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(open#1.base)]{\node(open#1){<#1>};}
}
\newcommand\close[3][red]{
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(close#2.base)]{
        \node(close#2){</#2>};
        \draw[#1,overlay](open#2)to[ncbar=#3](close#2);
    }
}

% second 'unknown' syntax
\newcommand\openvar[1]{
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(open#1.base)]{\node(open#1){<\uppercase{#1}>};}
}
\newcommand\closevar[3][red]{
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(close#2.base)]{
        \node(close#2){</>};
        \draw[#1,overlay](open#2)to[ncbar=#3](close#2);
    }
}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily

\open{b} nur fett \open{i} fett kursiv \close[green]{b}{.5cm} nur kursiv \close{i}{.7cm}

\bigskip\bigskip

\openvar{b} nur Fett \openvar{i} fett kursiv \closevar{i}{.5cm}\closevar[green]{b}{.7cm}\openvar{i} nur kursiv \closevar{i}{.5cm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update 2**

A slightly more efficient way of defining the `\close` command,  which has only two arguments:

```
\newcommand\close[2][red]{
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(close#2.base)]{
        \node(close#2){</#2>};
        \draw[ncbar,#1,overlay](open#2)to(close#2);
    }
}
```

Now it only takes two arguments:

1. The first, optional argument controls the line style of the "bracket". The default is currently set to `red`, and maybe changed to `[red,thick]` to produce a red and thick line if the optional argument is not given.

   - Note also that the `ncbar` option is now given to the `\draw` operation, so by default, the height of the bracket is `.5cm`. If a bracket of height .7cm needs to be drawn, just use `\close[ncbar=.7cm,<other options>]{<tag name>}`.
2. The second argument is the same as before: the name of the close tag.

With `\closevar` similarly modified, the above two examples can be implemented as

```
\open{b} nur fett \open{i} fett kursiv \close[green]{b} nur kursiv \close[red,ncbar=.7cm]{i}
```

and

```
\openvar{b} nur Fett \openvar{i} fett kursiv \closevar{i}\closevar[green,ncbar=.7cm]{b}\openvar{i} nur kursiv \closevar{i}
```

Comment: Related comment: I like your easy naming scheme of the nodes, but how do you implement the second example?

Comment: @Daniel. That's quite easy: change the defined commands: to `\newcommand\open[2][]{
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(open#2#1.base)]{\node(open#2#1){<#2>};}
}` (and similar for the other one). You should then be able to place the nodes using `\open{i}` (which makes the `openi` node) or `\open[A]{i}` which makes an `openiA` node. You can use the second syntax to point out ambiguities as in the second example, i.e. `\open[A]{b} \open[B]{b} \close[B]{b} \close[A]{b}`. Perhaps it would even possible to use LaTeX counters to do the grouping for you.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. I just need one more pointer: For printing, I need to use slightly thicker lines of the same color, but with different line styles - I'm sorry I didn't think about this when preparing the example. I noticed the `red` and `green` in your coding, but I don't understand how this is actually used by the commands. There's some magic going on that appears to be beyond my current knowledge - what do I need to read to catch up?

Comment: @vwegert: You're welcome. Notice that the first argument of the `\close` command controls the options to the `\draw` operation. Thus, if you want add more styles to the line, you can add more options to the first argument, and separate them using commas. For example, `\close[green,dashed,very thick]{b}{.5cm}` will connect the pair of `b` tags with a green, dashed, and very thick line; `\close[red,ultra thick,<->]{i}{.7cm}` will connect the pair of `i` tags with a red, "ultra thick" line with arrow tips on both ends.

Comment: @vwegert: To learn about other options available to the `\draw` operation, the [TikZ/PGF Manual](http://www.math.mun.ca/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) is a well-written and authoritative source (though it's quite long). [This question on TeX.SX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84753/18228) also contains links to other (shorter) summaries of the commands used in TikZ

Comment: @vwegert: Note that I've found a slightly more efficient way of defining `\close` command, so that it only takes two arguments. See Update 2 in the answer.

Answer (score 9):

With PSTricks just for fun. Compile it with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` or `xelatex` (slower).

```
\documentclass[preview,border=24pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}
\tt
\Rnode{A}{<tag>} contents \Rnode{B}{</tag>}
\ncbar[angle=90,arm=12pt,linecolor=red]{A}{B}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### PDFLaTeX version

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-node}


\begin{document}
This is a language:
\begin{postscript}
\tt
\Rnode{A}{<tag>} contents \Rnode{B}{</tag>}
\ncbar[angle=90,arm=12pt,linecolor=red,nodesep=6pt]{A}{B}
\end{postscript}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe one should add something like `\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr1em+12pt\relax}`? Otherwise the `\ncbar` will protrude in other content.

Comment: @Marienplatz: Cool, but for now I'm not really prepared to switch (back?) to XeLaTeX or DVI, coming from pdflatex...

Comment: Unrelated comment: `\tt` is not a LaTeX command, `\ttfamily` is correct. (`\tt` isn't even defined in the LaTeX kernel, it is provided by the class for compatibility reasons, try the same with `memoir`...)

Comment: @cgnieder: by the way: `memoir` has an option `oldfontcommands`

Comment: @Herbert I know :) I think it's still a good example...